# Store abbreviation using Solr in-built feature

Tags: solr

I want to make abbreviation of words using Solr. I am using Solr 7.1. In the schema, I have one field named "author", which is of data type string. Now I want to make another copy field from it which will store abbreviation of the string which is trying to store in "author" field. As example, "William Shakespeare" is going to store in "author" field, during addition "W. Shakespeare" will add in the copy field. I am very new in Solr and unable to configure it to fulfill the purpose. Please help.

Comment: Is your question about an algorithm of how to derive proper abbreviations or is it on how to apply the algorithm you have already available in Solr?

Comment: What is your expectation to how these abbreviations are generated?

Comment: I want to know whether any functionalities are present in Solr to fulfil my purpose or not?

Comment: I want to store a person name along with its abbreviation in two different fields(say, "Author" and "Auth_Abbr") in SOLR. And to fulfil this purpose I am looking up any possible functionalities/configurations of SOLR, which will automatically make abbreviation of the string, which is going to store in "Author" field, and store the abbreviated avlue in "Auth_Abbr" field.